# On AWS Free Tier, how to add SSL certificate to the URL that Elastic Beans generates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently running a web app at URL: http://cac-env.dbbgvdpgbn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ on AWS. I was wondering, how does one get HTTPS for this.

I found online tutorials that show how to use a certificate manager to get one. There, you have to enter the domain you are making a certificate for. Using the domain I listed above does not work (it is labeled as invalid).

Is there any way to do this without my own domain?

Comment: You should get a real domain and get the certificate for that. AWS's Certificate Manager won't let you provision one for an elasticbeanstalk.com domain.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you are talking about is with a self-signed certificate, but that really is only good for dev and testing purposes.  You'll get SSL warnings when you visit the site.  If that isn't an issue, you should be able to generate a self-signed cert with the Beanstalk domain name and upload it to ACM.  Then, you can use it in your Beanstalk config.  Or, if it's a single instance, you can install it directly on the instance and not worry about ACM.

In order to generate a certificate from a trusted authority, you need to be able to prove you own the domain (or are authorized to preform these actions).  So, your options are 1) create a self-signed cert and deal with the SSL warnings/errors or 2) get a domain name (Route53 allows you to register them, so you don't even need to leave AWS), and use ACM to create a cert.